# How can I list all files not hidden by my git-ignore files?

Tags: git, shell

I need to do the equivalent of `find` while respecting *.git/info/exclude* and any additional *.gitignore* files.

So far, the `git ls-files` suggestions all seem to fold in git semantics in ways that result in a list other than the one I seek.

To clarify: when no files are ignored, I want a full list of files, irrespective of their git status (tracked/untracked, up-to-date/modified, etc).  Now take that list and apply the exclude/git-ignore filter. That is what I need.

Comment: $ git ls-files -r -o --exclude-standard
error: unknown switch `r'

Without the -r this lists non-excluded untracked files.  It does not list unmodified tracked files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works well:

```
git ls-files --cached --modified --other --exclude-standard
```

If you also want to recurse into submodules, add `--recurse-submodules`.

Answer (score -1):

I think `git ls-files` can help you.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Comment: I had studied the suggested reference and have been unable to get the desired result.  (Please see my amended problem statement above.)